# Incorrect rendering of the language flag after system startup

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mate, language-support

After loading the system, the language flag is displayed incorrectly (in half of the proper area). After switching the language, the flag is displayed correctly. Do you know how to fix it:
[image: Screenshot]
?